# An unhandled exception of tpe 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, unhandled-exception

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

The above unhandled exception shows when i run below code :

```
Private Sub chUser()
    conn = New SqlConnection(conStr)
    conn.Open()
    myConn.clName = clNameDGV.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells(0).Value //EXCEPTION SHOWS FOR THIS LINE
    Dim comStr As String = "Select Count(*) from Login_Detail Where Clinic_Name = '" & clNameDGV.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells(0).Value & "'"
    Dim comm As New SqlCommand(comStr, conn)
    Dim i As Integer = comm.ExecuteScalar()
    If i = 0 Then
        If MessageBox.Show("No User Information found for '" + clNameDGV.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells(0).Value + "'." + vbNewLine + "Do you want to enter new user details ?", "No Users Found", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = vbYes Then
            Dim nf As New CreateUser
            nf.TopMost = True
            nf.ShowDialog(Me)
        End If

    End If

    Dim nf1 As New LoginForm
    nf1.TopMost = True
    nf1.ShowDialog(Me)
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

I have only one column with multiple rows in my datagridview. I run above function on doubleclick event of datagridview.

Comment: No rows are selected, I guess...

Comment: Please guide me what should be change in my code ?

Comment: add a test of clNameDGV.SelectedRows.Any() at the beginning of the sub

Comment: ... or check for `clNameDGV.SelectedRows.Count = 0` for more simplicity.

Comment: Incidentally, if you had a clinic name like "O'Malley" then your query would be broken. You should look into using SQL parameters to make your code more robust and resistant to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Adding to what @AndrewMorton posted. Wrap your connections and commands in `Using` statments so they are properly disposed of when you are done using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a one-column DGV, you only need to use the `.SelectedCells` property, and you should check that only one cell is selected, something like this:

```
Private Sub ChUser()

    If clNameDGV.SelectedCells.Count <> 1 Then
        ' not exactly one row was selected
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim clinicName As String = CStr(clNameDGV.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value)
    Dim nFoundRecords As Integer
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = Nothing

    Try
        conn = New SqlConnection(conStr)
        conn.Open()
        myConn.clName = clinicName

        Dim sql As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Login_Detail WHERE Clinic_Name = @ClinicName"

        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
            'TODO: Set the .SqlDbType parameter correctly.
            'TODO: Add the .Size parameter to match the setting in the database.
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@ClinicName", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Value = clinicName})
            nFoundRecords = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        End Using

        conn.Close()

    Finally
        If conn IsNot Nothing Then
            conn.Dispose()
        End If

    End Try

    If nFoundRecords = 0 Then
        Dim message As String = "No User Information found for '" & clinicName & "'." & vbNewLine & "Do you want to enter new user details?"
        Dim userChoice As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(message, "No Users Found", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

        If userChoice = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim nf As New CreateUser
            nf.TopMost = True
            nf.ShowDialog(Me)
        End If

    End If

    Dim nf1 As New LoginForm
    nf1.TopMost = True
    nf1.ShowDialog(Me)

End Sub
```

Please note how I have used `CStr` and `CInt` in appropriate places. If you use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) then it will point out for you where you should make explicit conversions (among other things). Also, I split up some lines into several lines to make it easier to read, and hence easier to edit.

Comment: @TarakBhavsar If you are happy with that answer, please accept it. That way, other people can see at a glance that your question was solved.

Comment: @TarakBhavsar You should see something like an outline of a green tick mark. You need to click on that to *accept* an answer. You can change your decision later if needed. Only one answer can be the accepted answer. You may want to go back through some of your previous questions and accept answers to them - it looks like you will get quite a few points by doing so.